# FFmpeg stream giving me "Alsa" errors

Tags: python, ffmpeg, youtube, live-streaming

Of late I have been trying different ways of telling my Raspberry Pi to send video to YouTube live stream. One of the things I wanted to be able to do is boot the Pi up, and it automatically starts the live stream on its own. The advantages to this are huge (won't have to tote around keyboard/mouse to start the stream, or have to ssh into the Pi to start the stream).

Now what I did to accomplish this was to make a Python program that pipes the stream from my encoder(FFmpeg) directly to the stream. My goal was to make the program work, and then, set it to run automatically. But every time I run the file in my terminal this is my result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stream.py", line 22, in <module>
    stream.stdin.close() 
NameError: name 'stream' is not defined
[h264 @ 0x19ed450] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264, none): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ Input #0, h264, from 'pipe:':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264, none, 25 tbr, 1200k tbn, 50 tbc
Unknown input format: 'alsa'
```

Now I think I can fix I can fix some of those errors, but the biggest thing that worries me there is: the fact that "alsa" is unknown. I installed "libsasound" which is supposed to make Alsa usable, but that clearly did not help.

I am using Python 3.

This is my syntax for this program:

```
import subprocess 
import picamera 
import time 
YOUTUBE="rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/" 
KEY = ("MY PERSONAL ENCODER KEY") 
stream_cmd = 'ffmpeg -f h264 -r 25 -i - -itsoffset 5.5 -fflags nobuffer -f alsa -ac 1 -i hw:1,0 -vcodec copy -acodec aac -ac 1 -ar 8000 -ab 32k -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -strict experimental -f flv ' + YOUTUBE + KEY 
stream_pipe = subprocess.Popen(stream_cmd, shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE) 
camera = picamera.PiCamera(resolution=(640, 480), framerate=25) 
try: 
  now = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S") 
  camera.framerate = 25 
  camera.vflip = True 
  camera.hflip = True 
  camera.start_recording(stream.stdin, format='h264', bitrate = 2000000) 
  while True: 
     camera.wait_recording(1) 
except KeyboardInterrupt: 
     camera.stop_recording() 
finally: 
  camera.close()
  stream.stdin.close() 
  stream.wait() 
  print("Camera safely shut down") 
  print("Good bye")
```

Now maybe I am missing something simple here, but I don't know what. I have tried many ideas (e.g. replacing Alsa with some other input, naming the "stream" function.) I have no idea.

Comment: Do you want audio? If yes, what audio input do you want (desktop, mic, specific application)? Your question is a basic "how do I use ffmpeg" question–the scripting is superfluous. So you can simplify things by running ffmpeg manually, and showing your actual ffmpeg command with the resulting complete console output. Only once you get ffmpeg working then you script it.

Comment: I already have FFmpeg working. I have streamed many times. I do want audio and i want it to come from a USB mircophone

Comment: You say "I already have FFmpeg working", but you get an error `Unknown input format: 'alsa'`.